# R - mlogit and mlogit.data - duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed

Tags: r, mlogit

Do you have an idea why the mlogit function is yielding an error?
*duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed*
The row names are not duplicate if you ask me. This is driving me crazy.

```
> mlORDERS <- mlogit.data(ORDERS, choice="PAYMENT_METHOD", shape="wide", id.var="ORDER_NUMBER")

> head(mlORDERS)
      ORDER_NUMBER CUSTOMER_ID PAYMENT_METHOD GROSS_RETAIL_TOTAL GENDER SOLVENCY_SCORE EXISTING_CUSTOMER chid alt
1.CCA 1.010311e+13     1402114          FALSE             1271.6   male            527              TRUE    1 CCA
1.INV 1.010311e+13     1402114           TRUE             1271.6   male            527              TRUE    1 INV
1.PPA 1.010311e+13     1402114          FALSE             1271.6   male            527              TRUE    1 PPA
1.PRE 1.010311e+13     1402114          FALSE             1271.6   male            527              TRUE    1 PRE
2.CCA 1.010311e+13      758980          FALSE               53.9 female            385              TRUE    2 CCA
2.INV 1.010311e+13      758980           TRUE               53.9 female            385              TRUE    2 INV

> str(mlORDERS)
Classes ‘mlogit.data’ and 'data.frame': 100 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ ORDER_NUMBER      : num  1.01e+13 1.01e+13 1.01e+13 1.01e+13 1.01e+13 ...
 $ CUSTOMER_ID       : int  1402114 1402114 1402114 1402114 758980 758980 758980 758980 217054 217054 ...
 $ PAYMENT_METHOD    : logi  FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE ...
 $ GROSS_RETAIL_TOTAL: num  1271.6 1271.6 1271.6 1271.6 53.9 ...
 $ GENDER            : Factor w/ 2 levels "male","female": 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ SOLVENCY_SCORE    : int  527 527 527 527 385 385 385 385 543 543 ...
 $ EXISTING_CUSTOMER : logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE ...
 $ chid              : num  1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
 $ alt               : chr  "CCA" "INV" "PPA" "PRE" ...
 - attr(*, "index")='data.frame':   100 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ chid: Factor w/ 25 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
  ..$ alt : Factor w/ 4 levels "CCA","INV","PPA",..: 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 ...
  ..$ id  : Factor w/ 25 levels "10103114445506",..: 20 20 20 20 1 1 1 1 18 18 ...
 - attr(*, "choice")= chr "PAYMENT_METHOD"

> mlModel <- mlogit(ORDERS$PAYMENT_METHOD ~ 1 | ORDERS$GENDER + ORDERS$SOLVENCY_SCORE, data=mlORDERS)
Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique value when setting 'row.names': ‘NA.NA’
```

I even tried `make.unique(rownames(mlORDERS))` and `which(duplicated(mlORDERS[, 1]))` which doesn't help neither.

Comment: `row.names(df) <- NULL` will give you the row numbers. `row.names(df) <- make.unique(row.names(df))` will append values to duplicate names to make them unique while preserving them if this is desired.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't solve it. I tried above command for unique row names but I still get the same error message. Also, there are no NAs when I look at the table. Must be a another reason not correctly expressed by the error message I fear...

Comment: In the meanwhile I could solve this:
Correct:  
`mlModel <- mlogit(PAYMENT_METHOD ~ 1 | GROSS_RETAIL_TOTAL + SOLVENCY_SCORE, data=mlORDERS)`
Wrong:  
`mlModel <- mlogit(ORDERS$PAYMENT_METHOD ~ 1 | GROSS_RETAIL_TOTAL + SOLVENCY_SCORE, data=mlORDERS)`